# MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem) return null

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I am trying to add actions items in my action bar using appcompat. I added search action when I click on it my application crash with `NullPointerException`. In `onCreateOptionsMenu` I am getting this view reference but there I am always getting `null`. Any suggestion to resolve this ??

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_search" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />


</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private SearchView mSearchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_bar_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_bar_search:
                mSearchView.setIconified(false);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Here I am getting null value in `searchView`

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_bar_search);
mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: See I am referencing correct ID `action_bar_search`

Comment: Now you edited but before it was `action_search`

Comment: show your imported file list.

Comment: coding part above this line public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity

Comment: import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

Comment: @Williams clean and rebuild the project. post the stacktrace

Comment: @Raghunandan I did but same issue still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed issue by setting Application Theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light`

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
   app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_search" />
```

You change showAsAction attribute.